# Python unsupported operand types errors

Tags: python, types, operands

I have code:

```
ds['annual_inc_per_experience']= round(ds.annual_inc/ds.emp_length, 2)
```

and error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str'
I have no idea how to fix it.

Please help.

Comment: what output would you expect to get for `1.0 / "foo"`?

Comment: Given its name, Its more likely that the casting should be done when setting the value of the field, not before doing an operation with it

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why it wasn't my first idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have string value in `ds.emp_length`. You might need to convert it to `float` or `int` first.

```
ds['annual_inc_per_experience'] = round(ds.annual_inc / pd.to_numeric(ds['emp_length'], errors='coerce'), 2)
```

Comment: I tried this and still have problem: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: @BookishMass, I updated an answer. Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

The **TypeError** itself has an idea of how to fix it, currently the `ds.annual_inc` is a type of `float` and `ds.emp_length` is a type of `str` so it is something like `1.0/"mass"`, that's why you are getting this error, you can `cast` the later one to `float` before the divide operation like below

```
ds['emp_length'].apply(lambda x: float(x)) 
ds['annual_inc_per_experience']= round(ds.annual_inc/ds.emp_length, 2)
```

Comment: I tried this and still have problem: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: @BookishMass did you try my latest solution?